# Pass a variable from Java to a Shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, variables, parameters

I am trying to run a shell script from a Java code. At the moment I am providing data manually in the script, but I would like to be able to provide the variables from the Java code that runs the script.

This is the Java code and the script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
              "/home/najib/upload.sh");
            Process p = pb.start();    
            p.waitFor();              
            System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
```

The shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="set AUTOCOMMIT MANUAL;"&
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="delete from DB.DBA.load_list;"&
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="SPARQL CREATE GRAPH <VAR1>;"&
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="ld_dir('/home/najib', 'VAR2', 'VAR1');"&
wait
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="rdf_loader_run();"
```

I would like to know where I can put the variables in the Java code, and how to then call it in run time!

**Edit:**
Based on the solutions provided, I changed the script to this:

```
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="SPARQL CREATE GRAPH <$2>;"&
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="ld_dir('/home/najib', '$1', '$2');"&
```

I also added an echo at the end of the script to see if the variables are being passed correctly, and it seems that they are. The first command (the SPARQL one) seems to work as the graph is indeed created, but the second one is not processed correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params to your shell script and use them inside de script, The Class  ProcessBuilder have a constructor that take the command to execute and the list of parameters to pass to the executable :

```
ProcessBuilder(String... command)
```

you have to pass params like this :

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/najib/upload.sh",param1,param2,param3);
```

inside the script param1 is $1 , param2 is $2 , and param3 is $3  (you can pass in the constructor as many arguments as you want )

Comment: Thanks! How can I check if the parameters are being processed correctly? Because when I try the script runs, The first SPARQL query is executed, but no effect is shown from the other commands of the shell script..

Comment: Try first with a simple script that echo params into a file , if it's ok then use your upload.sh

Comment: I added an echo at the end of the script and it seems that the variables are indeed being used correctly.. I just dont know why those commands are now not working.. I made an edit on the post, am I passing the variables correctly?

Comment: Here is what happens, when I put "term.rdf" as a variable, it does not seem to read it correctly in the command. when I read it as '$1.rdf' and I input only 'term' instead of 'term.rdf' in the java code, it works correctly.. any reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Use shell variables in the script, set them in Java through the environment:

```
import java.util.Map;

class so1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/...sh");
            Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
            env.put("VAR1", "something");
            Process p = pb.start();    
            p.waitFor();              
            System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In the script:

```
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba exec="SPARQL CREATE GRAPH $VAR1;"&
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I check if the parameters are being processed correctly? Because when I try the script runs, The first SPARQL query is executed, but no effect is shown from the other commands of the shell script..

Comment: You are running commands in background (with `&`). Maybe they are still running?