# Java Arguments, Terminal vs. Process

Tags: java, jar, args

When running a .jar file in two scenarios, the way the arguments are processed are different. The problem occurs when passing arguments with spaces.

Java uses space-delimiting for `args` however you can pass arguments with spaces in them, when surrounded by double quotes. I pass each argument with double quotes in case a user inputs an argument with spaces.

In one instance I run the .jar file on it's own via the terminal, and all of the arguments are processed fine:

```
java -jar jarFile.jar "key1=Tmp" "key2=This is a value."
```

Output:

```
Retrieving arguments: 
==> key1=Tmp
==> key2=This is a value.
```

Whereas in another instance I would like to execute this .jar from another Java class (Note: I do not want to create a class as I should, because I'm temporarily avoiding some bugs in the libraries I'm using) using the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + pluginPath + " " + "\"key1=Tmp\" \"key2=This is a value.\"");
```

Output:

```
Retrieving arguments: 
==> key1=Tmp
==> key2=This
==> is
==> a
==> value.
```

The functionality in the plugin for parsing the arguments is as follows:

```
    logger.info("Retreiving arguments: ");

    String[] kvPairs = new String[args.length];
    if (args.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            kvPairs[i] = args[i].replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            logger.info("\t ==> " + args[i]);
        }
    }

    // Enter the key-value pairs into a HashMap so we can retrieve the values easily.
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for (String entry : kvPairs) 
    {
          String[] keyValue = entry.split("=");
          map.put(keyValue[0].toLowerCase(), keyValue[1]);
    }
```

Where the last section is only pertinent to how I store the values after I parse `args`.

Is there any different functional difference in running the .jar from the terminal versus calling it via `Process` that could cause the same plugin to parse the arguments differently in the two scenarios?

Comment: Any reason not to use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: In the terminal app, it's not Java that's separating the arguments based on the spaces -- it's the terminal. Java actually gets them as separate args; there's not something internal that gets the full text of what you typed and parses out the individual args.

Comment: No reason not to use `ProcessBuilder`, I just had used `Process` and never heard of `ProcessBuilder`. Always learning in the software world. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's recomanded to use [ProccessBuider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) when managing params , check  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906717/pass-a-variable-from-java-to-a-shell-script/23907078#23907078)   it may help you. the java args are those passed in `public static void main(String[] args)` .