# Problems with file opening

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

For my A2 computing coursework I need to open and use media player or itunes from a Java program. the current code I have is so :-

```
    package random.file.opener; 

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class RandomFileOpener {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
    //this is to try to run internet explorer as a proof of concept
}
}
```

However this throws this error :-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iexplore.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at random.file.opener.RandomFileOpener.main(RandomFileOpener.java:19) Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:376)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 1 more
```

Java Result: 1

EDIT: However, I am able to run

```
    package random.file.opener; 

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class RandomFileOpener {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\taskmgr.exe");

}
}
```

Which runs perfectly..

Is there a specific way to deal with this error, as my code seems to be 'correct' but this error seems to keep bugging me.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why your error message shows the directory has the `Users` directory added to the path, but when I run your first code snippet it opens Internet Explorer as you described it should (JDK 1.7.0_60, Win 8.1 x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start some executable from your java application ,then it's recommanded to use [ProccessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) , where you will avoid the problem of having white space in your path , check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906717/pass-a-variable-from-java-to-a-shell-script/23907078#23907078) it may help you when using ProccessBuilder.

When you have to open file , browser or any GUI application from your Java program, you can use the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class that invoke the default application in your OS to open the specific file , example :

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
public class MyClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("myFile.txt");
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);

}
}
```

Comment: Can this Desktop class be used into any Environment? Like Linux or Windows or Mac etc? Also, is it a Java in-built class or is it from some library?

Comment: this might sound like a really rookie error, but the 'desktop' and 'file' classes just don't seem to work, ie they error with the IDE being unable to 'find symbol'. Am I missing something critical here?

Comment: @KeyurGolani yes Linux ,win & mac. and it's a java built-in class.

Comment: @tomandco did you import the required class ? do not forget to create the file that you want to open or use an already existing file in your machine.

Comment: thanks very much, it works with opening taskmrg.exe just not anything else! I think there may be some bug/error with opening anything from C:\\Program Files(x86) ?

Comment: @tomandco it could be a permission problem, try to launch your java application (or your IDE if you us it) as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code as yours. Copied it and created a class here. Made a few modifications to the path of my iexplorer.exe

But at my end it runs totally fine.

I suppose your path to the iexplorer.exe is having some issue.

Please make sure that you have the iexplorer.exe at the same path mentioned into the code.

Comment: When you pass `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe` to your path, why does it give error for `C:\Users\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` path?

Comment: The **User** folder is mistaken here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

if i test your code, it seems to work

Maybe you could try to run 64-bit IE instead, by just removing the (x86)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
```

But I suggest you navigate to your Programs Folder and search for Internet Explorer and then copy the path

Comment: I tried both of these with a variety of different paths to both, and different programs but it still gives me the same error?