# How to pass variables from Java to shell commands

Tags: java

I am using process builder to execute multiple shell commands (not external shell script) from Java. I can pass system environment variables to the shell command; However, if I want to pass on a variable defined in java (for example a string) as a argument to the shell command, how can I do that? My code looks something like this. I want two files to be created (touched) by name 123 & 234.

```
public class ExecShellCmds {

public static void beginWrite() {
    String var1 = "123";
    String var2 = "234";

    String s = null;
    try {
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c",
            "touch var1;"
            + "touch var2;"
        };

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}}
```

Comment: Look here. I think this would be usefull: [Pass variable to shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906717/pass-a-variable-from-java-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: If you show us the code you have, we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I do not want to run external script but would like to directly call multiple commands from with in java code

Comment: "touch " + var1 + ";"

Comment: Modified the lines as given above, it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments (and the program) are stored in a `List<String>`, you can get a reference to this list with [ProcessBuilder.command()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command()), you can then just add your parameters to this list.